# Unhandled exception while working with duplicate tabs on Google Chrome [ADFS]

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, telerik, adfs

I have a dot net based application that I am trying to run on Google Chrome. It uses ADFS for authentication. I am able to log in successfully, but when I create a duplicate tab and switch between tabs and then come back to the main tab to click on any link or any menu item from the telerik rad tree, an unhandled exception message appears with no relevant or helpful information. This works on IE but does not work with version 96 of Chrome that I am currently working on. I have been debugging as well to find problems  in the code if any, but no success so far. Please suggest what should be the things that I can look into.

Comment: if you use active directory, its best to stick with IE. that being said, you might better off contacting telerik support for the issue given your error message and code doesnt seem can be published on public. hopefuly they can solve your problem.